# Use avg() and joins mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table called students

```
idStudent    Name

1            Billy
2            Mariah
3            Chris
4            Mark
5            Sarah
```

and another table called tests

```
idTest score student_idstudent

1      50      1
2      100     1
3      90      2
4      100     3 
5      45      4
```

is it possible to use a combination of a join and avg() to get a result like

```
idStudent     avg_test
1             75
2             90
3             100
4             45
5             0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.idStudent,
       AVG(COALESCE(t.score, 0)) AS avg_test
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN tests t
    ON s.idStudent = t.student_idStudent
GROUP BY s.idStudent
```

Comment: Thank you, one more question though. Is it possible to display the average multiplied by the number of actual tests for each student? So for example Student 1 (Billy) it would show 75 * 2 = 150. I know in this scenario it doesn't really make sense but I'm trying to do a weighted average by the number of scores given.

Comment: Sure, just use `COUNT(*) * AVG(COALESCE(t.score, 0))`